# Do you have any methods for going from Camera Roll to a new view controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, imageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to go from Camera Roll to a new view controller. So basically I want to be able to choose a picture and after choosing the picture, it will be displayed on an imageView on a new view controller? Is that hard to make ?

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
(NSDictionary *)info{
self.chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.imageView setImage:self.chosenImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You can push a viewcontroller in didfFinish method of image picker.

Comment: Do not duplicate your questions.

Comment: I duplicated it because no answered my other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a property of UIImage in the targetViewController
and then add the below code in didFinish method

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.imageView setImage:self.chosenImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    TargetViewController *targetViewController = [[TargetViewController alloc]init];
    targetViewController.imageProperty = self.chosenImage;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Than you so much , I appreciate it.